# Standard for order of tags in PHP DocBlocks?

Tags: php, documentation, coding-standards, documentation-generation, annotations

Based on the tags listed from [this "standard"](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#8-tags), is there an order of the tags that people typically follow? Even if it's not something that has been entirely accepted, but something proposed? I am trying to enforce a coding standard for a project, and it would be nice to have a guideline of what order I want our tags to be in.

Also, do tag orders change based on the element? (Files, Classes, Methods, etc.)

Comment: See [this Stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30235371/102937).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks. There are 20+ tags, though, so I feel like there should some sort of standard. There are so many options to order that many tags. I'll just come up with my own standard for now, but hopefully in the future the PHP community will decide on something.

Comment: Do not waste time coming up with your own standard, instead, have a look at existing projects and see how they do it. For reference,  also see https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/pull/169.